# Unanswered Question Archeology Event Proposal

Tags: discussion

I want to propose an Unanswered Question Archeology event.  We've had a couple of rough weeks as we've gone through the split process with Sound Design, but now we're getting back in the swing of things.  What I propose is that we setup a day or weekend where we look through the unanswered question queue and work on providing answers to as many of the questions as we can.

We've gotten a lot of new, active faces lately and I think we can get great answers for a good portion of the unanswered questions.  As an added incentive, I will front a rep bounty for the top contributor for the event (maybe even the top few contributors if it's really successful).  I'll base the exact amount of rep on how many questions we answer and the quality of the answers (number of up votes received in the week following).  There is also the possibility of some SE swag being donated to the cause if participation is significant enough.

Comment: [Data Explorer Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/avp/query/172886/votes-for-answers-on-questions-unanswered-for-30-days-and-first-answered-after-gi) that can identify the data.

Comment: This has worked well on various other sites. If you like, I'll pitch in with a bounty as well. Oh, and swag - that's always a good thing!

Comment: [Data Explorer Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/avp/query/172890/questions-unanswered-for-30-days-as-of-or-after-the-given-date) that can identify the questions that we would work from.

Answer (score 4):

I think this sounds like a great idea and would be interested in participating.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, but don't know if I could participate at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this idea would work well and don't wish to participate. (Feel free to comment with suggestions if you think it can be improved or why you think it wouldn't work.)